# Retrieve a password stored as env variable in Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, apk

I am using Jenkins to build my Android application. When building an Android app, there is a step where the build is signed with a distribution certificate. I have configured this into Jenkins and it works perfectly:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore $KEYSTORE_FILE -storepass $STORE_PASS -signedjar $SIGNED_APK $INPUT_APK $KEYSTORE_ALIAS
```

the `$STORE_PASS` is injected as an environment variable. After one year... I forgot the correct password but I would like to be able to also sign manually my android app. In the Jenkins, the password is obfuscated and in encrypted in `config.xml`. Does someone know if there is a way to see the password in clear or to retrieve the password by an other mean?

Comment: see my edited answer , new trick hope it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment variable should be accessible in-job, but it will be encoded in config, **and may be starred out in console output**. However, do the following

- Configure "Execute Shell" build step
- Type `echo $STORE_PASS > mypass.txt`
- Run the job once
- Review the text file `mypass.txt` in the root of your Workspace `http://JENKINS_URL/JOB_URL/ws/mypass.txt`

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is googling "sha1 decoder online" and try your luck.

Comment: As the question mentions, passwords are stored encrypted by Jenkins, not hashed (as that wouldn't make sense).

Answer (score 0):

Use google chrome , Right click in Default Value section of password parameter and after that click on inspect element. you can see the actual password.. try this

Comment: password is still obfuscated when I do that